# Why are the comments not showing up in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a ruby on rails blog as part of my project. I wanted to add comments to my blog. However, the site takes the comment and stores it successfully but when it comes to showing the comments, it doesn't work. I checked if the comment was registered using the rails console and it is registered. The github repository for it is : https://github.com/rocka0/blog-in-rails

Note: If specific code is needed, please let me know in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/rocka0/blog-in-rails/blob/master/app/views/posts/_comments.html.erb#L1

I think it should be:

```
<%= div_for @comments do |comment| %>
```

I'm a bit surprised it does not throw any error here.

Edit: You also don't set `@comments` instance variable anywhere in the controller: https://github.com/rocka0/blog-in-rails/blob/master/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb#L13 You should do it or use `@post.comments` instead.

Comment: so what would the div_for with @post.comments look like? Forgive me im a rookie in ror

Comment: @comments = Post.find(params[:id]).comments is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

In the _comments.html.erb

```
<%= div_for @comments do |comment| %>
        <p>
                <strong>
                        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
                </strong>
                <br/>
                <%= comment.body %>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

In the posts_controller.rb

........

```
def show
    @comments = @post.comments
    respond_with(@comments)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Comments Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))

        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
end
```